# CodeIgniter: view is not generated in a certain case

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, codeigniter-2

Starting from a variable called **$data**, which is an associative array which includes an object, and whose printed value is this:

```
Array
(
    [item] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [tipo] => 0
            [idioma] => es
            [nombre] => Artí­culo de prueba
            [titulo] => Esto es un artí­culo de prueba
            [alias] => articulo-de-prueba
            [texto] => Lorem ipsum etc etc
            [url] => 
            [video] => 
            [fecha_c] => 2012-11-27 10:50:37
            [fecha_m] => 2012-11-27 17:00:00
            [fecha_p] => 2012-11-28 00:00:00
            [destacado] => 0
            [status] => 1
        )

    [imagenes] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I need to filter its value and assign it to another array, this way:

```
protected function load_form($data = '') {
        $this->load->helper('form');

        // If item data have been sent, pass it to the form view to edit it.
        // Else display empty form for new item.
        if (! empty($data)) {
            // Data can be an associative array with an object and another array or just an object           
            if (array_key_exists('item', $data)) {
                $this->_vars['item'] =& $data['item'];
            }
            else {
                $this->_vars['item'] =& $data;
            }
            if (array_key_exists('imagenes', $data)) {
                $this->_vars['imagenes'] = $data['imagenes'];
            }
        }

        $view = $this->load->view(ADMIN_FORMS_PATH . $this->_controller . '_form', $this->_vars, true);

        /*DEBUG*/ echo $view; // just for debugging purposes
}
```

The first assignment generates these errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   item Filename: core/Admin_Controller.php Line Number: 205
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Object of class
>   stdClass could not be converted to int Filename:
>   core/Admin_Controller.php Line Number: 205

It behaves like the item index doesn't exist, and it does. Also, it tries to convert the object to an integer.

Why does it happen and what should I do to fix it?

**EDIT:**

I was doing &= instead of =&. That's the reason of the errors.

Anyway, the problem persists and the code seems to stop.

**EDIT2:**

Trying to redefine the problem. It might be something related to CodeIgniter, so I've added the whole function, including CodeIgniter functions.

The load_form() method can be invoked from a request to create a new item, in which case $data is empty, or from a request to edit a given item (in $data). In the first case (creation), the debug line is executed, but not in the second case (edition).

Comment: Could you show us line 205 of Admin_Controller.php?

Comment: @Fabio: line 205 is the first assignment: $this->_vars['item'] =& $data['item'];

Comment: Does `$this->_vars` exist and it's an array?

Comment: @sierrasdetandil: It wasn't initialized as array with new array(). Now it's done, but the mystery remains.

Comment: I'm starting to think it might have something to do with my CodeIgniter implementation. That's why I've added the whole function involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was too simple.

It was inside the view. I was trying to echo:

**$item['id']**

instead of

**$item->id**

The item data is being retrieved as an object, not an array. It was causing the problem silently, without any warning, notice or error.

Anyway I appreciate your quick help.

Answer (score 0):

This may be your issue. Near the end you have"$datos['imagenes'];" where it should be "$data['imagenes'];"

```
if (! empty($data)) {
    // Data can be an object, or an array with object + array of images            
    if (array_key_exists('item', $data)) {
        $this->_vars['item'] &= $data['item'];
    }
    else {
        $this->_vars['item'] = $data;
    }
    if (array_key_exists('imagenes', $data)) {
        $this->_vars['imagenes'] = $data['imagenes'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo. It's not the real problem. I simply changed $datos to $data for clarity. I've just corrected it.